# Accessibility: v-dialog in Vuetify showing element as having role="document" instead of role="dialog

Tags: dialog, vuetify.js, accessibility

I am building a v-dialog https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/dialogs/ using Vuetify.

Though when I inspect the element in the browser it says the role of the dialog is role="document" instead of role="dialog". Does anyone have an idea why?

Here is a screenshot of the v-dialog element

[image: 1]

[Here is a bigger screenshot of the dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZMZK.png)

Comment: When I inspect the dialog from the link you posted, it very well has a `role="dialog"`. If you’re not using a different version, there must be something in your code that messes with this parameter. Could you share more, like how you are integrating the dialog, and how are you opening it?

Comment: Yeah exactly, the component on vuetify shows role="dialog".

I have put the dialog as its own component and I am calling it from the parent:
`    <Modal
      v-model="showModal"
      @close="closeModal"
    />



    openModal() {
      this.showModal = true
    },
`

Comment: I am wondering if it has to do with the wrapping around it? Have added a larger screenshot to the question.

Comment: I took a look at the vuetify source code, and nowhere do they assign `role="document"` to anything. The issue must lie within custom code or browser extensions. Which browser are you using, and can you reproduce the issue with a clean browser session or another browser?

Comment: Yeah, even if I clear the cache - or if I'm using a different browser (have tried safari and chrome) the problem still occurs. I don't even have `role="document"` anywhere in the codebase ...

Comment: Might it be an old version of vuetify? Which one are you effectively using?

Comment: yes! Andy, sorry it took me a while to getting round to this, but once I upgraded vuetify from 2.3.10 to 2.6.10 - modals have changed from role="document" to role="dialog" - thanks for the suggestion!